# Accidently deleted windows partition on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader, testdisk

I have accidentally deleted my Windows partition (using fdisk) including the system partition. I was able to recover the partitions using Testdisk however I can't see an option too boot into Windows.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? You may need to run chkdsk on each NTFS partition to make repairs, or use your Windows repair disk for other repairs. Also if BIOS boot partition must be NTFS with boot flag. IF UEFI the ESP - efi system partition must be FAT32 with boot flag. Really a Windows question and this is an Ubuntu question & answer site.

Comment: Hey oldfred. Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry if my question doesn't belong here. I thought maybe because I'm using Ubuntu tools to solve the problem it can be somewhat relevant to this place. Anyways, I have UEFI. I will try the solution you proposed. I hope it works out. Thanks anyways for your reply and support.

Comment: Btw, I have an image.dd of my partitions using Testdisk. Do you think there's a way to write them to the disk and get the problem solved?

Comment: If Windows, testdisk may not even see the Microsoft system reserved (MSR) since it is just unformatted space. Then the start of your main install is too far forward. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: Thanks for your help oldfred. I figured it out. Now I have another issue if it's possible for you to help me with. So I wanted to expand my Ubuntu ext4 partition. I used fdisk. What I did is that I deleted the ext4 partition then created one with the same starting sector but larger size. I ended up losing all my data. Do you happen to know a way to recover that? I have already tried testdisk, photorec with no hope. Thanks again for all your support

Comment: You should have just been able to resize with gparted from Ubuntu live installer ore gparted ISO. Testdisk deeper search & then photorec would be my choices. If you have done those, then restore from backup is only other option that I know. Some other possible options: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery